# ajax.actionlink insertionmode insertafter for table

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

if I have a table with a variable number of `<tr>` elements,

```
<table id="my_table">
 <!--there could be 1 tr or 3, don't know, server decides based on database-->
 <tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>c</td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

and I have an `Ajax.Actionlink` with `InsertionMode.InsertAfter`, where I want to insert a new `<tr>` do I target `"my_table"` or do I have to target the last `<tr>` that I have?

if it's the latter, that means I'll have to give the last `<tr>` element a dynamically generated id value so that I can access that one, is this correct?

is there an easier way to do this? or am I misunderstanding how insert after works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include a hidden tr at the end of your table and then use insertionMode.Replace

```
<table>
   <tr id='1'>
      <td>something</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id='replaceme' class='hidden'><tr>
</table>
```

don't forget that your replacement html should include another `<tr id='replaceme'>`

The really should have an insertionmode.append and prepend

Comment: I'm retarded, thank you for making me aware of my slowness... can't believe I didn't think of this lol, thanks for enlightening me

Comment: I agree, I was thinking of append

Comment: just thinking, I think I need "ReplaceWith" for this solution because replace replaces everything inside the hidden tr element, however ReplaceWith replaces the tr element itself. If I'm replacing only the contents inside the hidden tr, I can't have a tr in the partial view being returned, because it will be nested within the hidden tr in the main view... you follow me? not sure if I'm making sense